# How to set strict-transport-security in serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I am working on serverless project, I have serverless.yml and inside this I want to set strict-transport-security to all lambda function under api gateway,
this is what I tried in serverless.yml but when I invoke this function I don't see this header,

What I tried

```
functions:
  someLambda:
    handler: src/someHandler.list
    events:
      - http:
          path: somePath
          method: get
          response:
            headers:
              strict-transport-security: "'max-age=3600'"
```

I expected after I invoke this lambda, I get back strict-transport-security set as response header, can someone please tell what is that going wrong? Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated